# Pandas Stack() Unanticipated Result

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas stack() operation is producing some unanticipated results in practice that I am unable to replicate with a small working example. I'm curious if others have run into this behavior and if there is a likely explanation for the root cause. First, a small reproducible example that demonstrates what I am trying to do:

```
data = {'kpiOne': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
'kpiTwo': [3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
'kpiThree': [5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6],
'PrePost': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', ]}
dfr = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfr = dfr.groupby('PrePost').describe()
dfr = dfr.stack(0) #this is where my problem is in practice, but works fine in this example
dfr
```

Here is the code that I am using with the actual data in case there is anything relevant here:

```
kpiSum = dfr[(dfr.filter_any == False) & (dfr.version == 'After')].groupby('waveTwoExp')[kpi].describe()
kpiSum = kpiSum#.stack(0)
kpiSum
```

The output looks like this before (comment symbol in place) I stack(0):
[Before stacking][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMTAK.png

The output looks like this when I remove the comment symbol and stack(0):
[After stacking][2]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXZ7.png

If you look closely you'll notice that the values have been incorrectly stacked. The mean for the KPI, 'uarl' before stacking is correct - 765. After stacking, the mean for the KPI 'uarl' is from the next level 0 column, 'alCost', or 797484. I cannot figure out why this shift is occuring.

What makes this very strange is that:

1. My reproducible example does not exhibit this behavior and more
   importantly:
2. My code to stack(0) worked fine before I upgraded to Jupyter 5.0

Please let me know if my question is clear! Anyone else running into this behavior?

Thanks!
Kris

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me investigate this! My pandas version is: 0.20.1

Comment: I wonder if it is related to this bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898426/multiindex-reshaping-differences-between-pandas-versions/43914593#43914593 .... [16325](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16325)

Comment: Can you go back to .19 and test?  This documented bug should be fixed in a few days with version 0.20.2 expected release June 13, 2017.

Comment: I just downloaded 0.20.2 where this bug has been fixed (I guess it is already available?). Thank you so much for pointing me to the other question -- I had not been able to find it before posting my own!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try upgrading or downgrading a version.

This appears to be a bug related to [MultiIndex/Reshaping differences between Pandas versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898426/multiindex-reshaping-differences-between-pandas-versions/43914593#43914593).