# Pandas iterrows() row.get() method returning series instead of cell value

Tags: python, pandas

The situation: Pandas' dataframe's `iterrows()`'s row behaves differently in two different environments. In one, `row.get()` returns a value as expected, in the other `row.get()` itself returns a series - which is unexpected.

The question: Are there pandas settings/some configuration that could cause the following behavior to differ between two environments? I acknowlege not all information is present in this example. What I hope is possible is that, shown the following behavior, someone might recognize that this is the result of some common pattern or, perhaps, settings change.

Details:
While in the first environment, I iterate through rows via the Pandas' `iterrows()` method. In each row, I access a given attribute, like so:

```
print(type(row)) # pandas.series.Series

foo_val = row.get('foo', default=None)

print(type(foo_val)) # float
print(foo_val) # 234.23
```

Now when I run again, in the second environment; the `iterrows()` operation returns a `row` variable. It appears normal but getting (`row.get()`) each element behaves differently than before. Specifically, a returns value won't be an int, float, str, etc. but rather itself a Series, with the index preserved, such that:

```
print(type(row)) # pandas.series.Series

foo_val = row.get('foo', default=None)

print(type(foo_val)) # pandas.series.Series
print(foo_val) 
# foo      234.23
# Name: 0, dtype: object

foo_val_v2 = foo_val.get('foo', default=None)

print(type(foo_val_v2)) # float
print(foo_val_v2) # 234.23
```

Final thoughts:
I seem to recall at some point that you're able to configure pandas to return indices with row values, but maybe I'm imagining things.

I should also note that printing `row` in both situations renders identical results, as does logging each column type, row type, etc. That is, I can assert that the row type is the same, the column types within the parent dataframe are the same, and the type for each row element is the same.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's going to be very difficult for anyone to be much help.  Many bug fixes in pandas have come about via SO (e.g. just recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898426/multiindex-reshaping-differences-between-pandas-versions/43914593#43914593)), but that requires something to start with.

Comment: Thanks, I acknowledge it's a problem that I can't isolate what's wrong to reproduce. For that reason, this may be a bad SO posting. I'm doing this on the off chance someone recognizes the issue or has encountered in the past. In the meantime, I am trying to better isolate it (but have been coming up dry all day, hence the hail mary here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Had I done a more thorough job profiling the dataframe, I might have noticed the column name duplication.

The reason for the Series being returned instead of a single value was because, through a `.rename()` operation far upstream, there were two columns with the same name. As a result, Pandas behaved (as it should) and returned both as a Series when that column value was requested.

Below is a self-contained example.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})

>>> df.rename(columns={'B': 'A'})
   A  A
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

>>> df['A']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

>>> type(df['A'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})

>>> df = df.rename(columns={'B': 'A'})

>>> df['A']
   A  A
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

>>> type(df['A'])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```