# How to sort pivot table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'country':['us','ca','ru','cn','ru','cn','us','ca','ru','cn','us','ca','ru','cn','us','ca'], 'month':[5,6,7,5,6,7,5,5,6,7,5,6,6,5,5,6], 'id':[x for x in range(16)]})
p = test.pivot_table(index=['month', 'country'], aggfunc='count')[['id']]
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to sort the table by the `id` column, so that the largest number appear on top like:

```
                    id
month    country
           us       4
  5        cn       2
           ca       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
p1 = p.reset_index()
      .sort_values(['month','id'], ascending=[1,0])
      .set_index(['month','country'])
print (p1)
               id
month country    
5     us        4
      cn        2
      ca        1
6     ca        3
      ru        3
7     cn        2
      ru        1
```

because this solution does not work :(

```
p1 = p.sort_index(level='month', sort_remaining=True) \
      .sort_values('id', ascending=False)
print (p1)
               id
month country    
5     us        4
6     ca        3
      ru        3
5     cn        2
7     cn        2
5     ca        1
7     ru        1
```

Comment: @ScottBoston - really hard question, I try find some issues about it in pandas github but uncessfully. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
This sorts by `id` within groups defined by the `month` level within the index

```
p.groupby(
    level='month', group_keys=False
).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, by='id', ascending=False)

               id
month country    
5     us        4
      cn        2
      ca        1
6     ca        3
      ru        3
7     cn        2
      ru        1
```

---

**Option 2**
This first sorts the entire dataframe by `id` then sorts again by the `month` level within the index.  However, I had to use `sort_remaining=False` for self-explanatory reasons and `kind='mergesort'` because `mergesort` is a stable sort and won't mess with the pre-existing order within groups defined by the 'month' level.

```
p.sort_values('id', ascending=False) \
 .sort_index(level='month', sort_remaining=False, kind='mergesort')

               id
month country    
5     us        4
      cn        2
      ca        1
6     ca        3
      ru        3
7     cn        2
      ru        1
```

---

**Option 3**
This uses numpy's `lexsort`... this works, but I don't like it because it depends on `id` being numeric and my being able to put a negative in front of it to get descending ordering. /shrug

```
p.iloc[np.lexsort([-p.id.values, p.index.get_level_values('month')])]

               id
month country    
5     us        4
      cn        2
      ca        1
6     ca        3
      ru        3
7     cn        2
      ru        1
```